# Positive correlation between temperature and refractive index of water?

Tags: temperature, water, refraction

I am currently doing an experiment on refraction for physics class where I am looking at the relation between refractive index and temperature of water. The result I got was the the refractive index and temperature of water share a positive correlation, but based on resources I have seen online this should not be the case. I am wondering; are there any reasons why increasing temperature might also increase the refractive index of water?

*Experiment: I had a shallow rectangular box of water with an angled mirror on the bottom and a laser straight above it pointing down. The laser enters perpendicular to the water, bounces off the mirror at an angle, and then exits the water and refracts. I found the angles of incidence and refraction by forming two imaginary triangles with the two angles, measured two sides, and then used Snell's law to find the refractive index of water.

Comment: Could you explain what the experimental setup has been used?

Comment: I had a shallow rectangular box of water with an angled mirror on the bottom and a laser straight above it pointing down. The laser enters perpendicular to the water, bounces off the mirror at an angle, and then exits the water and refracts. I found the angles of incidence and refraction by forming two imaginary triangles with the two angles, measured two sides, and then used Snell's law to find the refractive index of water.

Comment: How the temperature of water has been changed and measured?

Comment: I used a vernier temperature probe submerged in the water. because of the size of the box, a small end of the probe was not submerged.

Comment: Could you show your experimental data?

Comment: Temperature: 65.0 62.5 60.0 57.5 55.0 52.5 50.0 47.5 45.0   42.5   40.0   37.5   35.0
Laser Height on Wall: 83.2 85.8 88.2 90.0 92.4 95.0 97.0 98.6 100.8 102.9 104.4 106.0 107.2
Water Surface to Wall Distance: 341.5
Water Surface to Submerged Mirror Distance: 2.2
Water Entry to Exit point Distance: 2.1